# Laravel 4 - How to get the latest in with() for each record in one query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm working on a messaging system in laravel 4. I have the following tables users, conversations, conversation_user(pivot) and messages. users and converations have many to many relationship, conversations have many messages and users have many messages. I get the conversations of a user like so:¨

```
$usersConversations = Auth::user()->conversations;
```

Then I loop over them to get their ids to be able to select only those messages users and messages like so:

```
if(0 < $usersConversations->count()) {
    foreach ($usersConversations as $conversation) {
        $conversationIds[] = $conversation->id;
    }
    $conversations = Conversation::with('users', 'messages')->whereIn('id', $conversationIds)->get();
} else {
    $conversations = false;
}
```

but this returns all users and all messages for each of the conversations. I wan't all the users but only the latest message for each conversation. So I tried doing this instead:

```
$conversations = Conversation::with('users', 'latestMessage')->whereIn('id', $conversationIds)->get(); 

// and have this in my Conversation model
public function latestMessage() {
    return $this->hasMany('Message')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1);
}
```

This does get me the latest message, but only the very latest, and only one, no matter how many convesations there are. I wan't one message for each of the conversations.

Can anyone help me with how to construct that query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want the latest conversation/message of all the users ?

Comment: No only for conversations the logged in user is in. And only the latest message of each of these conversations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for.

```
$conversations = Conversation::with(array('users', 'messages' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->take(1);
})->get();
```

There is no need to use the `latestMessage` function.

**EDIT**: The item returned will be a collection if the relationship is not a 1-1. Even if you use `first()` instead of `take(1)`. Honestly I think it's not intended, but to work around this, make sure to output your messages as such:

```
foreach($conversations as $conversation){
    echo $conversation->messages->first()->YOUR_FIELD;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried using first instead of take(1) but it throws a "Call to undefined method" exception. The problem with your solution is that I will end up querying the database  once for every conversation in the list, which I want to avoid by using eager loading.

Comment: @mr2_kasper I cracked my head on this a little... check if this meets your need ;)

Comment: Something I found out: using first() instead of take(1) runs an extra query

Comment: using the ´function ($query)´ gets me the same as my latestMsesage function, which I prefer because it makes the code more readable and reusable I think. ´$conversation->messages->first()->message´ throws a 'trying to get property of non-object exception. I think there's no way around running a query for each of the conversations. Because of this I think I will make a solution where I load up the users conversations with their messages and users and store it in a session so I only have to query for new conversations and messages. Does this sound as a good or bad solution?

Comment: Actually, I tested this and it works. Regarding the error: YOUR_FIELD is a column of the messages table. I don't have your code at hand, but trust me when I say that this code works exactly the way you want.